# Interview Question: Can all duplicates in a vector be removed in O(n) time and O(1) space?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I was asked the following question today: Can someone share an O(n) solution (with constant space) to the following problem, if possible?

/******************************************************************************

Complete the following function that takes a vector of integers as an argument
and removes repeating values such that at most two instances of the same value
remain in the vector. The order of remaining elements must be preserved.

For example, given the following input:
0, 10, 10, 100, -1, -1, -1, 5, 5, 5, 8, 9, 10, 10, 3, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0

This function should output
0, 10, 10, 100, -1, -1, 5, 5, 8, 9, 3, 9, 7, 0

******************************************************************************/

My answer:

```
/* 

My assumptions:

1. There is no guarantee they will be in 
sorted order and/or grouped together.
2. You can have at most two instances of the same value, 
meaning it's fine if I have one instance.

I feel like the fact that there can be at most two instances 
of the same value means that it can be
done in O(N) space and O(1) time... Thinking...

*/

// Naive first solution using more space. O(N) time and O(N) space.
void deduplicatePartial(std::vector<int>& vec) {
    vector<int> resVec;
    resVec.reserve(vec.size());
    unordered_map<int, int> numMap;
    for (int i{}; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        auto iter = numMap.find(vec[i]);
        if (iter == numMap.end()) { // If I can't find this number in my map, 
            resVec.push_back(vec[i]); // put it in my result vector.
            numMap[vec[i]] = {1}; // Make entry to map.
        }
    }
    vec = std::move(resVec); // Rip its guts out.
    //vec = {resVec.begin(), resVec.end()};
}
```

Comment: isn't there an 0 missing in the `output 0, 10, 10, 100, -1, -1, 5, 5, 8, 9, 3, 9, 7, 0` at the end?

Comment: @DevFlamur No, the input has three zeros, and there can be at most two. The output has two zeros, where the last one was removed.

Comment: you mean that zero at the beggining counts too? because the output expects at the end 1 zero to remain not 2 zeros...

Comment: @DevFlamur Reread the question, it says "removes repeating values such that at most two instances of the same value remain in the vector.". One again **at most** two instances... So I'm assuming one instance of the same object is fine. I documented my assumption. They decided to include the second instance of zero, which appeared in the vector 4 times. But, they didn't **need** to. Am I making sense?

Comment: Are you sure it can be done in constant space ?

Comment: @steviekm3 I am not. That's why I am asking here :) Seems strange that they said you can keep at most two items. It must mean something. Or am I reading too much into it?

Comment: Would radix sorting it count? The complexity would be something like (bits+1)n => O(n)?

Comment: I see very similar question here with solution. www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/amp/

Comment: @steviekm3 The condition there is "Given an array of n elements which contains elements from 0 to n-1, with any of these numbers appearing any number of times. " Not the same. I think the only way is using extra space here.

Comment: @tomer it seems that way to me, but I wouldn’t be surprised either if there was a solution

Comment: An O(n) time and O(1)  space approach is to create a zero initialized array which can hold all possible  `int`  values (that has O(1) size  as its size is a constant, independent of n; this array can also be initialized in O(1) time). You'd then simply count the number of times you have seen a value in a suitably indexed cell in that array and remove elements if you have seen 2 already. This part's time complexity depends on n, of course, but can be done easily in O(n) time.

Comment: Given the way the problem is worded, wouldn't `vec.clear();` produce, in O(n) time and constant space, the result of removing elements from `vec` such that at most two instances of each value remain in the vector? It's probably not an intended solution, but since the requirement is "at most" rather than "exactly"... ;)

Comment: Interview questions might not have a right answer, but are meant to get you to talking about the problem. One talking point to bring up is this solution depends on a hash map being O(1), but that's only the case if you have a perfect hash of the inputs. That won't exist for the full int range (unless you have 18tn buckets), so you'd ask if the inputs can be constrained, etc. Likewise, you can _have_ constant space at the expense of O(N) time, which you could talk about.

Comment: Trie of binary bits?

Comment: @DietmarKühl an "array which can hold all possible int values" is not `O(1)` for our purpose here. Taking the entire domain of a C++ integer as a constant would invalidate complexity analysis for the great majority of algorithm questions on Stack Overflow as well as competitive programming and instructional websites.

Comment: (LTR) @גלעדברקן: True, but note that `calloc` of very large amounts of space is so much faster than actual memory *access* on modern systems that it’s an approach worth mentioning.

Comment: @DavisHerring UPDATE: I passed the interview, so I guess my method was alright!